# Create Google sheets shortcut in homescreen

Tags: ios, google-apps

This [quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-create-an-icon-shortcut-on-the-iPhone-iOS-7-home-screen-that-links-directly-to-an-specific-Google-Docs-file-a-spreadsheet-on-Google-Drive/answer/Adi-Mishra-1?srid=n4hS) instructs on how to create a shortcut to a sheet in mobile  safari

I would like to have an icon on iOS springboard (home screen)  to tap and open a specific spreadsheet document in the google sheets app.

Can this be done natively with automation scripting or with a helper app?

Answer (score 11):

I see that all of my line breaks were removed in the answer. Let's fix that!

---

Open the document in GoogleDocs app on your iPhone.

Tap the three dots in the top corner

Share & export

Copy link

Leave the GoogleDocs app and open Shortcuts app

---

Create Shortcut

Add Action

Search for Safari

Open URLs

Tap the little gray field that says URL

Type googledocs://

Tap and paste (the link you copied from GoogleDocs). The result will look something like http://googledocs://https://docs.google.com/document/d/bunch-of-random-characters

Tap where it says “New Shortcut” at the top in big bold letters and name the shortcut

---

Tap the three dots

You can change the icon (the gray square with the magic wand in it) to what you want and give it a shortcut name.

Tap Add to Home Screen

Add

Done

Done/Next

---

Voila! You now have an icon on your home screen for the document, which will automatically open in GoogleDocs.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent!  you had the following sentence: Create Shortcut Add Action Search for Safari Open URLs Tap the little gray field that says URL Type googledocs:// Tap and paste (the link you copied from GoogleDocs).  I cannot find the Add Action Search shortcut. Is that because I'm on an iPad instead of an iPhone.  I don't see any punctuation in that sentence?  Should there be some?  Maybe it's me my eyes are old - like me! lol

Comment: See Nick Barthram answer below, which added just enough detail to make the process clear.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/443582/53510

Comment: Just want to say, the exact steps have changed a bit since this was written, e.g. there's no "..." button at one point when it's mentioned, but the overall process still works. Look around and you'll find the right places to tap to get the shortcut set up.

Comment: using `googlesheets://` instead of `googledocs://` did the trick

Answer (score 4):

Much simpler way to add a Link icon for Google Drive/Sheets file to iPhone home screen:

1. Open Safari;
2. Go to google.com;
3. Open your account;
4. Open Google Drive (or Sheets);
5. Open File;
6. Click ... in upper right corner;
7. Click Share and Support;
8. Click Copy Link (this is the URL of the Drive/Sheets file);
9. Open a new web page in Safari;
10. Paste the copied link in address bar;
11. The Drive/Sheets file will open;
12. At bottom of page click the Share icon (box with an up arrow);
13. In the second bar of options click Add to Home Screen;
14. You did it!

Comment: This will still open it in Safari though. OP is wondering how to open it in the Sheets app.

Comment: thank you @DanLeveille i indeed unfortunately downvoted this answer

Answer (score 3):

*Pamela's answer worked perfectly for me, but I can see in comments there is some confusion so here it is edited. I don't have enough reputation to add this as a reply hence new answer...*

Open the document in GoogleDocs/GoogleSheets app on your iPhone.

Tap the three dots in the top corner Share & export Copy link

Leave the GoogleDocs/GoogleSheets app

open Shortcuts app

Create Shortcut

Add Action

Use the search box and type "Safari", scroll down to see 'Open URLs' and tap

Tap the little gray field that says URL Type googledocs://

Tap and paste (the link you copied from GoogleDocs). [If you are using GoogleSheets type googlesheets:// instead.]

The result will look something like http://googledocs://https://docs.google.com/document/d/bunch-of-random-characters

Tap the '...' next to where it says “New Shortcut” at the top in big bold letters and name the shortcut and you can change the icon (the gray square with the magic wand in it) to what you want. Tap done.

Tap the 'share' icon at bottom of screen and then Add to Home Screen Add Done Done/Next

Voila! You now have an icon on your home screen for the document, which will automatically open in GoogleDocs or GoogleSheets.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please don't add comments in an answer or repost an answer already provided.  You can earn reputation by providing good answers to other questions.

Comment: I think this answer adds clarity to a correct but somewhat unclear answer he refers to. I don't think dinging this answer is called for given that he correctly credited the original answer and that his answer is significantly more useful.

Comment: @snuggles This answer from Nick would probably have better worked as an edit to the answer it is referring to.

Answer (score 3):

[Pamela's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384348/237) / [Nick Barthram's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/385468/237) answers do what the OP wants, *IF* you type "googlesheets://" instead of "googledocs://" At least on my iPhone, "googledocs" took me to the Google Docs app, where the target spreadsheet wasn't.

The only way I've found to open a a file to a particular tab/page is to move it to the first position.

Answer (score 2):

This helps for the previous two sheets you worked on, if you are using 3D Touch.

Use quick actions on iPhones with 3D touch

You can open recent spreadsheets, use templates, and create new spreadsheets with quick actions. To see recent spreadsheets in the menu, turn off the passcode lock.

Note: This is only available if you have 3D Touch on your iPhone (iPhone 6s/6s+ or newer).

To get to the quick actions menu, hard tap the Google Sheets app. The quick actions menu will open.
From the list, tap one of these options:
The last two spreadsheets you opened or edited.
Templates: Opens the template menu.
Create: Creates a blank spreadsheet.
Your spreadsheet or template will open in the Google Sheets app.

From: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6000292?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en